# How to tell if an image contains a specific color?

Tags: colors, images

Is there a command line tool to tell me if an image contains a specific color? For example, if it contains `#ff0000`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org) with command:

```
convert  image.ext -colorspace RGB -format %c  -depth 8  histogram:info:-|grep -i '#ff000'
```

`convert` program will convert the image to 8 bits, RGB (CMYK image will give fake results) and build histogram with output like:

```
...
       422: (  0,255,255) #00FFFF cyan
       126: ( 46,139, 87) #2E8B57 SeaGreen
...
```

and you will need to filter the desired colour.

Comment: `#ff0000` is a 24-bit colour. Why do you say you're reducing to 8 bits?

Comment: @roaima, 8bits per channel :D

Comment: Although from testing, there might be a 4th 8 bits value (the alpha channel) in the picture so better use `grep -i '#ff0000'` to not match on this last part. It's usually FF (not transparent) except for pictures like icons.

Comment: @A.B, right, will correct it. Same is true about CMYK so will convert the image explicitly to RGB :)